# rand_r() versus rand() in approximation of pi

Tags: c, random, seeding

I am trying to approximate pi for homework by using a Monte-Carlo method, by randomly sampling points in a unit box, and counting the ratio that falls inside a unit circle enclosed by the box. See below. I am asked to do this in parallel using multithreading but decided to get things working first before parallelizing things. My teacher has hence explicitly asked me to use rand_r() for thread safety. I am aware that better pseudo-random number generators exist. However, I cannot seem to get things right, and I figure I am seeding rand_r() the wrong way. I have tried to seed using the computer time, but the value I get is wrong (around 2.8). If I use some random number and seed rand() with srand() instead, I am able to approximate pi pretty easily. Can anyone enlighten me as to what I am missing here? The code I have written looks like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

double randomNumber( unsigned int seed){
  /*_Thread_local*/
  double maxRand      =   (double)RAND_MAX;           // Maximum random number, cast to double
  double randNum      =   (double)rand_r( &seed );    // Generate pseudo-random number from seed, cast to double

  return 2 * randNum/maxRand - 1;                     // Recast number between -1 and 1
}

int main( void ){

  unsigned int seed         =   time(NULL);

  int numOfPts              =   (int)1e8  ;
  int ptsInCircle           =   0         ;
  double unitCircleRadius   =   1.0       ;

  double xpos   =   0;
  double ypos   =   0;

  for ( int iteration = 0; iteration < numOfPts; iteration++ ){
    xpos = randomNumber(seed);
    ypos = randomNumber(seed);

    if ( sqrt( pow(xpos, 2) + pow(ypos, 2) ) <= unitCircleRadius ){
      ptsInCircle++;
    }

  }

  double myPiApprox = 4.0*((double)ptsInCircle)/((double)numOfPts);

  printf("My approximation of pi = %g\n", myPiApprox);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aside: Not that is make much difference here, yet `double maxRand = (double)RAND_MAX;` looks like leads to a biased position.  I'd expect  something more like `(rand_r(&seed) + 0.5) / (RAND_MAX + 1.0)`.  Hmm might make for a good SO question ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not updating `seed` each time through the loop.

`rand_r()` updates the local variable `seed` in the `randomNumber()` function, but that doesn't affect the variable in `main()`. The result is that you're generating the same random number every time you call it.

You need to pass a pointer to `main`'s variable to `randomNumber()`.

```
double randomNumber( unsigned int *seed){
  /*_Thread_local*/
  double maxRand      =   (double)RAND_MAX;           // Maximum random number, cast to double
  double randNum      =   (double)rand_r(seed);       // Generate pseudo-random number from seed, cast to double

  return 2 * randNum/maxRand - 1;                     // Recast number between -1 and 1
}

int main( void ){
  unsigned int seed         =   time(NULL);
  int numOfPts              =   (int)1e8  ;
  int ptsInCircle           =   0         ;
  double unitCircleRadius   =   1.0       ;
  double xpos   =   0;
  double ypos   =   0;

  for ( int iteration = 0; iteration < numOfPts; iteration++ ){
    xpos = randomNumber(&seed);
    ypos = randomNumber(&seed);
    if ( sqrt( pow(xpos, 2) + pow(ypos, 2) ) <= unitCircleRadius ){
      ptsInCircle++;
    }
  }

  double myPiApprox = 4.0*((double)ptsInCircle)/((double)numOfPts);
  printf("My approximation of pi = %g\n", myPiApprox);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this makes a lot of sense. It seems I misunderstood the point of the seed. It works now, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are:

1. reseeding the random number generator on each iteration instead of letting it do it's thing, and
2. not only are you reseeding each iteration, you use the same seed for `x` and `y`, so you're only creating elements on the diagonal (where `x == y`)

   EDIT: in the original question you used `randomNumber(iteration)`, which would generate sorta-random numbers on the diagonal, in your edit you changed it to `randomNumber(seed)`, which is always the exact same value.

Change the definition of `randomNumber`:

```c
double randomNumber(unsigned int* seedp) {
  // ...
  double randNum      =   (double)rand_r(seedp);
  // ...
}
```

and your loop:

```c
for ( int iteration = 0; iteration < numOfPts; iteration++ )
  xpos = randomNumber(&seed);
  ypos = randomNumber(&seed);
  // ...
}
```

Comment: You are right about the first point. My original post was slight nonsense, hence the edit. I do however believe both directions should be seeded as `xpos = randomNumber(&seed); ypos = randomNumber(&seed); ` such as the answer above by @Barmar suggests, otherwise i guess they would be the same number sequence. In any case, using different seeds do not work.